# Should I not ask and answer very basic questions?

Tags: discussion

I asked an, admittedly, *incredibly basic* python [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752071/how-can-i-run-python-code-directly-from-the-command-line-not-running-a-python-f), and I was immediately and immensely down-voted. All of the points that the (probable) down-voters raised were valid:

- > You're literally asking how to run Python? This is covered in the first page of the Python tutorial.
- > Is this a problem that people are actually having? I can't imagine a time when I'd want to do this. Plus, this whole thing boils down to "Launch Python if you want to use Python."

Basically all of my python experience has been through IDE's (almost all of my coding experience has been in IDE's), and I never learned this *very basic principle*.

I asked *and answered* this question because I was unable to easily find what I was looking for, *because I didn't know what I was looking for*. I created the question as a synonym for "Interactive Mode", because before today, I had never heard of it.

Should I not ask and answer questions like this? If I am supposed to, what makes this particular question atrocious?

Oh, and as I side note, I tried to include this context in the question, because I wanted the intent of the question to be clear, but it is being removed.

Comment: There were comments on your question answering all of these meta questions.   The fact that you've quoted them here and stated that they're valid concerns should imply that you don't need to ask this meta question, since you not only know the answer, but you even agree with it.

Comment: Does Googling `How can I run python code directly from the command-line` not answer the question sufficiently? If it does, there doesn't seem to be a need for another question

Comment: All the links it resulted in were about running python files.

Answer (score 11):

You are expected to have done your research before asking a question on SO.  While it's *possible* to have a very easy question that's well researched, and for which there simply isn't relevant information out there on the subject, that is *quite* rare.  Extremely easy introductory questions like this are virtually always readily answerable by other existing resources, as is the case with your question, and the votes reflect that.

> Oh, and as I side note, I tried to include this context in the question, because I wanted the intent of the question to be clear, but it is being removed.

Indeed.  The question is where you ask your question, not where you explain why you decided to ask a question.  Including context relevant to how the question might be solved, or the greater application that you're trying to solve with the question would be fine, as that is often relevant to an answer, but meta commentary on the question has no business being in the question, and so it is appropriately being removed.

Answer (score 0):

Without going to your linked question and judge it:

> I asked and answered this question because I was unable to easily find what I was looking for, ...

In general creating self answered *canonical Q&A* is appreciated at Stack Overflow.

But both parts should meet our current basic post policies:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Then it's maybe welcome, if not covered by another duplicate already<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Trivia likely is answered with a duplicate, so don't repeat!

Comment: That was more or less my intention, so I asked this question to see what i did wrong.

Comment: @CacheStaheli That's why I've been trying to give you the keypoints.